# Stack initialisation in GNU ARM toolchain

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m, gnu-toolchain

Checking the startup file provided as an example in the GNU ARM toolchain, I couldnt understand one thing.

Code snippets provided here are taken from examples included in GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain files downloaded from [official website](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads). **Code compiles and everything seems to be good.**

I am wondering why they wrote this code exactly like that, why they are using same names for example?

I am wondering why my linker is not complaining about multiple definition error for `__StackTop` and `__StackLimit`. Here is the part of the file `startup_ARMCM0.S`

```
    .syntax unified
    .arch   armv6-m

    .section .stack
    .align  3
#ifdef __STACK_SIZE
    .equ    Stack_Size, _*emphasized text*_STACK_SIZE
#else
    .equ    Stack_Size, 0xc00
#endif
    .globl  __StackTop
    .globl  __StackLimit
__StackLimit:
    .space  Stack_Size
    .size   __StackLimit, . - __StackLimit
__StackTop:
    .size   __StackTop, . - __StackTop
```

If the linker is defining the same symbols: `__StackTop` and `__StackLimit`.

```
.stack_dummy (COPY):
    {
        *(.stack*)
    } > RAM

    /* Set stack top to end of RAM, and stack limit move down by
     * size of stack_dummy section */
    __StackTop = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
    __StackLimit = __StackTop - SIZEOF(.stack_dummy);
    PROVIDE(__stack = __StackTop);
```

While checking linker documentation, it was written that, given the example:

> ```
> SECTIONS
> {
> .text :
>     {
>     *(.text)
>     _etext = .;
>     PROVIDE(etext = .);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, if the program defines `_etext` (with a leading
>   underscore), the linker will give a multiple definition error.  If, on
>   the other hand, the program defines `etext` (with no  leading 
>   underscore),  the  linker  will  silently  use  the  definition  in 
>   the  program.   If  the program references `etext` but does not define
>   it, the linker will use the definition in the linker script.

Also, when using `readelf -s` just to check symbols generated from assembly file `startup_ARMCM0.S` without linking, I can see the symbol `__StackTop` and `__StackLimit` with one values. While, after linking they have the values set up by the linker (keeping in mind that the value of the linker is actually stored in address of the symbol).

Comment: I have never ever seen anyone align their code using `.align  3` This means you are aligning your code over 3 bytes = 24 bits which is weird... Usualy it is 4 bytes = 32 bit or in the past there was 2 bytes = 16 bits.

Comment: @71GA Look, this code is written by the Gnu Toolchain Arm people, I am sure they know how it should be done.  And, you are not right here- `.align 3` means align by 2^3=8. Take a look here https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html

Comment: @artlessnoise I dont agree with you. Please look the section which I copied from linker manual. Also, take a look at linker manual (https://doc.ecoscentric.com/gnutools/doc/ld.pdf ) Page 55 what `Provide` does.

Comment: You do not have `PROVIDE(__StackTop=xxx)` nor `PROVIDE(__StackLimit=xxx)`. `PROVIDE(__stack = __StackTop)` would have a multiple of `__stack` only which is not in the assembler.  Am I reading the manual incorrectly?

Comment: .align should be avoided with gnu assembler as each target defines what n means (bytes, power of 2, etc) .balign is preferred if I remember right as it is consistent, wish I could find the article that describes the problem.  what artless noise said basically

Comment: certainly the addresses defined in asm will not get their values until link time.  and if you define things in two places then you will get a conflict.  not sure what the question is.

Comment: @old_timer talk to ARM. BTW no oone uses their startups :)

Comment: @Vaso did you compile and link it?

Comment: @artlessnoise Not sure if I understand you correctly. My understanding is that when I put `Provide` then it is allowed for variable to be overwritten by some other definition in program. I tried using `PROVIDE(__StackTop=xxx)` and defining `__StackTop` in code also - No complaints from the linker.

Comment: @old_timer I added one more question for clarification: I am wondering why they wrote this code exactly like that, why they are using same names for example? Also, I am not sure if the answers for my other questions are answered here.

Comment: @P__J__ Hey, yes it compiles, everything works good! Just wondering why is it like this, one kind of startups you think I should be using?

Comment: @Vaso the one which suits you the most. There is no one simple answer to this question

Comment: @P__J__ I certainly dont use canned startups no desire to talk to ARM any more than i have already.

Comment: @Vaso you should ask the folks that wrote this why they did what they did if this is a why did they do that question, how are we supposed to know we didnt write it.    They should have a support channel or forums or some such thing...

Comment: @old_timer Can you give some advice, I am writing a code for stm32f103, one larger project. I want to set it up with GNU ARM toolchain. I saw some examples provided by answers here on StackOverflow as well through the internet. But these canned startups from ARM seems to be the best from what I found so far on this topic. How I can find out about the best practice for stm32 development with GNU?

Comment: no such thing as best practice, and certainly not for bare metal.  I prefer to talk to the registers directly, many/most folks use the sandbox/libraries provided by the chip vendor.  ST has at least one if not two options HAL and something else.  IMO valuable to be able to work either way.  Pretty easy to use GNU (or llvm or other) if you make your own bootstrap and linker script.  Ideally easy to use the sandbox too if you dont make waves (if they support windows use windows if it is mac use mac if it is linux use linux)...

Comment: gnu is just a tool though and overly flexible so it is really up to you, these already made generic linker scripts and bootstraps are going to be overly complicated as an example for trying to figure out how they work...

Comment: @old_timer For now I am using just CMSIS, also trying to work with registers as much as possible. I think the bootstrap script they provided is not complicated. I think just that I am missing something, because it is not working the way I expect it to be when it comes to these names and linker script connection. On the other side, linker script is bit more complicated, many sections I dont know anything about are mentioned there. For now I added generic linker and bootstrap scripts, they work fine for now. What are your suggestion about writing linker and bootstrap scripts, any resources?

Comment: @Vaso  I still don't think that follows the manual.  For some reason they have `_etext` in the linker and without under bar `PROVIDE(etext)`.  This under bar often depends on the architecture.  It certainly makes sense that the linker will replace the variables with definitions inside the script; this is its job.  Check that you are not  using gold.  Also generate a map file, it is a great tool to diagnose linker issues.